# Knockoutjs binding JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am have a problem binding a JSON result with knockout js.  Below is my code

```
var AddDeparmentViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
self.AddDepartmentModel = {};
$.getJSON('/EventTracker/Department/GetEmptyModel/', function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.AddDepartmentModel);
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
var departmentViewModel = new AddDeparmentViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(departmentViewModel);
})
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="titleWrapper">
        Add Department
    </div>
    <label>Department Name:</label>
    <input data-bind="value: AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName" id="departmentNameTextbox" type="text" />
    <p data-bind="text: AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName"></p>
```

The values I am returning are not appearing.  Could someone point out where my mistake is.  In this case the server is returning a single object not an array of objects.

Thanks!

Edit:

The Server returns this JSON:
{"DepartmentID":0,"DepartmentName":"Test","EVNTTRKR_Admins":[],"EVNTTRKR_Event":        [],"EVNTTRKR_ItemCategories":[]}

Edit:

Here is the function GetEmptyModel:

```
 public JsonResult GetEmptyModel()
        {
            var eventT = new EVNTTRKR_Departments();
            eventT.DepartmentName = "Test";
            return Json(eventT, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the JSON you're binding to?

Comment: You're saying the server is returning a 'single object', which means the issue might be on the server.  What are the contents of the data object from the getJSON call? (you can either user console.log to show it, or set a break point, or use Fiddler to see the data sent down the wire).

Comment: The json that is being returned is : {"DepartmentID":0,"DepartmentName":"Test","EVNTTRKR_Admins":[],"EVNTTRKR_Event":[],"EVNTTRKR_ItemCategories":[]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having seems to be fairly common. You are creating observables **after** binding the viewmodel. When this happens there is nothing for knockout to hook into and nothing gets rendered. A fix for this would be to make sure `AddDepartmentModel` is an observable and to set it to the return value rather than overwritting it with the fromJS.

```
var AddDeparmentViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;   
    self.AddDepartmentModel = ko.observable({}); //important to have a default value so bindings dont break
    $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function(data){
        var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);        
        self.AddDepartmentModel(data); // here we are pushing values into the observable
    });
};
```

This also requires fixes to the bindings as they now need to invoke `AddDepartmentModel` as a function:

```
<input data-bind="value: AddDepartmentModel().DepartmentName" id="departmentNameTextbox" type="text" />
```

Example fiddle with json request and population in callback.
http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/YWC9N/

Comment: If I update the textbox the label is not updating.  Why is this.  Is it possible to make it update?

Comment: I figured it out.  Instead of the last line reading self.AddDepartment(data), it needs to be self.AddDepartment(mapped) since mapped has the observable properties.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zupQt/) and replaced your getJson call with your server data (because I cannot call your getJson url). And it all seems to work which leads me to believe that an error is occuring in the getJson call.

Could you open your browser developer tools and look for any errors in the console. If there is an error and you're not sure what it means, add the error information to your original problem description.

```
var AddDeparmentViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;   
    self.AddDepartmentModel = {};
    var data = 
        {"DepartmentID":0,"DepartmentName":"Test","EVNTTRKR_Admins":[],"EVNTTRKR_Event": [],"EVNTTRKR_ItemCategories":[]
        };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.AddDepartmentModel);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var departmentViewModel = new AddDeparmentViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(departmentViewModel);
})
```

Comment: I added an alert() in the success function for $.getJSON and the alert is happening.  I am not sure why it is not binding.

Comment: There are no errors.  I don't understand why I cannot get this to work with a single object.  I was able to get it to work with an array of objects.  :(